# R regular expression repetition ignores upper bound

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I try to make regular expression which helps me filter strings like

```
blah_blah_suffix
```

where suffix is any string that has length from 2 to 5 characters. So I want accept strings

```
blah_blah_aa
blah_blah_abcd
```

but discard

```
blah_blah_a
blah_aaa
blah_blah_aaaaaaa
```

I use grepl in the following way:

```
samples[grepl("blah_blah_.{2,5}", samples)]
```

but it ignores upper bound for repetition (5). So it discards strings     blah_blah_a, 
    blah_aaa, but accepts string blah_blah_aaaaaaa.

I know there is a way to filter strings without usage of regular expression but I want to understand how to use grepl correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bound the expression to the start and end of the line:

```
^blah_blah_.{2,5}$
```

The `^` matches beginning of line and `$` matches end of line.  See a working example here: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zH8rR2)

If you want to bound the expression to the beginning and end of a string (not multi-line), use `\A` and `\Z` instead of `^` and `$`.

[Anchors Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[\w]+_[\w]+_[\w]{2,5}$/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rE2vL8)

```
Options: dot matches newline; case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «[\w]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “_” literally «_»
Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «[\w]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “_” literally «_»
Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «[\w]{2,5}»
   Between 2 and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{2,5}»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```